# Update multiple rows with random figures

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

Below is a button event handler called `Password_Click`. When you click on this button it goes into the database and finds a table called `TblMaintenance`.  Once in the table it finds all records in the table where the field `Patrol` = True or 1 and Updates the field `Password` (also in the table) with a system generated random 4 digit number.

My issue is each row will update with the same random guard password. I want each row to have a different random 4 digit number. At the minute it’s doing this which I don’t want it to do:

SITE   Password              Patrol
CEP            5405           1
GNK            5405           1
ILT            5405           1
KHA            5405           1

But I want it to do this instead:

SITE          Password       Patrol
CEP            4567           1
GNK            9000           1
ILT            4345           1
KHA            1278           1

```
protected void lnkPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var i = random.Next(1000, 9999);

    SqlHelper.ExecuteSqlNonQuery(@"update Tblmaintenance set
                                   GuardPassword = @newPassword
                                   WHERE Patrol = 1",
                                   "newPassword", i);                        
}
```

Comment: You gotta remember to seed your Random Number Generator once you've finished testing it

Comment: Since you're generating passwords you should really be using a cryptographically strong random generator, not `Random`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it with a one DML statement you can use the following:

```
update tbl_Security set
                           GuardPassword = round(rand(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS SMALLINT))* 9000,0) + 1000
                           WHERE Patrol = 1
```

It should generate new four figure number for each row that comply with the where statement.

Comment: That's excellent. your method worked perfectly. Thank you very much. do you mind explaining to me what the code means please? I haven't used that statement before

Comment: Sure.
NewID() - generate unique identifier - which I then convert to VARBINARY, and then to INT.
Rand() - generate random number between 0 to 1 (with floating point).

The reason that I've multiplied by 9000 is because I've needed to get the floating point number - 0.xxxxxxxx - to be at the form of xxxx.xxxxxxx. It should have been 10000, but I've changed it to 9000 and added 1000 to make sure that the result number will be between 1000 and 9999.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a DataContext (dbml in Visual Studio) you can use LINQ rather than SQL to bring back records and edit them using C# code.

```
DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();

foreach(T2_keyHolderMaintenance t2 in (from t2 in db.T2_keyHolderMaintenances where t2.ManageGuardPatrol == true select t2).ToList())
{
   t2.GuardPassword = Math.Random() //or whatever you want to do
}

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Why the `ToList`?  There's no need to eagerly evaluate the entire query into a separate data structure to foreach over it.

Comment: Thanks James for your reply

Answer (score 1):

a little workaround for your issue could be:

```
protected void lnkUpdateGuardPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //command = query to select all the yard codes.

    List<string> YardCodes = new List<string>();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        YardCodes.Add(reader["YardCode"].ToString());
    }

    var random = new Random();
    foreach (var yardcode in YardCodes)
    {
        var i = random.Next(1000, 9999);
        SqlHelper.ExecuteSqlNonQuery(@"update T2_SecurityKeyHolder set
                               GuardPassword = @newPassword
                               WHERE YardCode = @yardcode",
                               "newPassword", yardcode, i); 
    }                       
}
```

this will first get all the yardcodes (assuming they are unique), then set a random for each individual yardcode.

Comment: If you have a *lot* of entries this doesn't scale quite so well and you may need to batch the responses to reduce the network traffic.  For smaller data sets this is fine though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, most helpful!!. you guys are great

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your SQL statement.  It is updating ALL records where ManagedGuardPatrol value equals 1.  They all will have the same GuardPassword value every time the click event is called.  You need to use YardCode to identify which record to update.

To clarify, the random number is generated in C# and passed into the SQL statement once.  This same value is propagated through all matching rows.

```
i = 4505; // a number that was randomly generated ONCE.
```

Your SQL statement becomes:

```
update T2_SecurityKeyHolder 
set GuardPassword = 4501
WHERE ManagedGuardPatrol = 1
```

which updates all matching records with the **one** random value.

If I can think of a clearer way to explain it, I will.  For the moment, suffice to say, you are only generating one SQL statement with one fixed value.

Comment: could you please write me an example to help me understand please. If you don't mind please

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void lnkPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlHelper.ExecuteSqlNonQuery(@"update Tblsecurity set
                                   Password = abs(checksum(NewId())) % 10000
                                   WHERE Patrol = 1");                        
}
```

or

```
protected void lnkUpdateGuardPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlHelper.ExecuteSqlNonQuery(@"update Tblsecurity set
                                   Password = ROUND(((9999 - 1000 -1) * RAND() + 1000), 0)
                                   WHERE Patrol = 1");                        
}
```